# how to store the value from html dropdwon list to use in the same page

Tags: php, html

I have this code -

```
<form method="post" action="generate.php">
    <select name="test" id="Test">
    <?php
       $i=0;
        foreach($testName as $name){
    ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $name;?>"><?php echo $testName[$i];?></option>
    <?php  $i++; } ?>

    </select> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate">
</form>
```

How I can store the value selected by user in a way that I can use it in the same php page?

Comment: I don' understand your question

Comment: @touchpad -  in php we get the selected value after submitting the page, here my need is to get the value as soon as user selects it in the drop down list

Comment: well in that case I see no other way than putting them in the same form, give them all different names and then check the `$_POST['test']` in this case on page reload (if I understand you coorectly)

Comment: in that case your only choice is javascript

Answer (score 1):

Store the value in a hidden field with javascript/jquery like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden">
```

and call an `onchange` event on select element.

```
<select name="test" id="Test" onchange="test()">
```

Write corresponding js function,

```
<script>
 function test()
 {
  var selectedval=$("#Test").val();    // get selected value
  $("#hidden").val(selectedval);       // set the value of hidden field
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Just to point out that for the javascript function you need to have jQuery available on your page.

Comment: @Jenz - without js its not possible ?

Comment: As you are doing whole in a single page and needs to be done on clicking of drop down, you require js ..

Comment: actually I have two drop-down lists and I want to get the value from both and thn do something.

the problem here is that I cant use the same "action =" for both the drop down list

Comment: As I don't know the context in which you are doing this, I can't find any other solution for this. What about doing the same method for the other drop down also..

Comment: It is also better to send the element to the function directly rather than using jquery to fish it out, takes the guesswork out when dealing with classes. For id's it isn't a problem usually

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in a hidden field with javascript/jquery like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden">
```

Write some jQuery Code to assign value to hidden field on change on drop down:

```
<script src="PATH/TO/JQUERY"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
 $("#Test").live("change", function() {
  $("#hidden").val($(this).val());
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This also works. I was going to use jQuery in my example but I leaned in favor of pure javascript. Also note that after jQuery 1.7, `.live("change", function(){ });` becomes `.on("change", function(){ });` Source: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You can set an onchange handler to the form element to run javascript when the form option is selected. Here is an example (using your code):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select name="test" id="Test" onchange="formChangeFunc(this)">
    <?php
    $i=0;
    foreach($testName as $name)
    {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $name;?>"><?php echo $testName[$i];?></option>
    <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
</select> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate">

</form>

<script>
function formChangeFunc(sel) {
  alert(sel.value);
  document.getElementById('divIdToInsert').innerHtml(sel.value);
}
</script>

<div id="divIdToInsert"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The example should give you an alert popup when you change the option. This should also insert the value into the specified div container.

Comment: this I UNDERSTAND but is there a way to use this value in the  php script in same php script ?

Comment: Unfortunately not because php runs before the page is sent and displayed, then the browser runs the javascript. The only way to achieve this is by using ajax in the javascript event handler to a php script that can handle the request.